# How to create a listener for bottom navigation and navigation drawer in the same activity?

Tags: java, android

//Here is my java code

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    NavigationView navigationView;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull final MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.home:
                    HomeFragment homeFragment=new HomeFragment();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout,homeFragment).commit();
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_stylist:
                    StylistFragment stylistsFragment=new StylistFragment();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction1.replace(R.id.frameLayout,stylistsFragment).commit();
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_apps:
                    MyapptsFragment myaaptsFragment=new MyapptsFragment();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction2.replace(R.id.frameLayout,myaaptsFragment).commit();
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_tips:
                    HairtipsFragment hairtipsFragment=new HairtipsFragment();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction3=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction3.replace(R.id.frameLayout,hairtipsFragment).commit();
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_account:
                    AccountFragment accountFragment=new AccountFragment();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction4=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction4.replace(R.id.frameLayout,accountFragment).commit();

                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //start onboarding when app is opening first time
        isUserFirstTime = Boolean.valueOf(Utils.readSharedSetting(HomeActivity.this, PREF_USER_FIRST_TIME, "true"));
        Intent introIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, OnboardingActivity.class);
        introIntent.putExtra(PREF_USER_FIRST_TIME, isUserFirstTime);

        if (isUserFirstTime)
            startActivity(introIntent);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        navigationView=findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer);


        //bottom navigationview listener
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);

        //navigation drawer listener
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        //open home fragment on first launch
        HomeFragment homeFragment=new HomeFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout,homeFragment).commit();

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                HomeFragment homeFragment=new HomeFragment();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout,homeFragment).commit();
                return true;

            case R.id.nav_products:
                StylistFragment stylistsFragment=new StylistFragment();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction1.replace(R.id.frameLayout,stylistsFragment).commit();
                return true;

            case R.id.nav_promotions:
                MyapptsFragment myaaptsFragment=new MyapptsFragment();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction2.replace(R.id.frameLayout,myaaptsFragment).commit();
                return true;

            case R.id.nav_purchases:
                HairtipsFragment hairtipsFragment=new HairtipsFragment();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction3=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction3.replace(R.id.frameLayout,hairtipsFragment).commit();
                return true;

            case R.id.nav_settings:
                AccountFragment accountFragment=new AccountFragment();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction4=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction4.replace(R.id.frameLayout,accountFragment).commit();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

// Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:theme="@style/menu_text_style"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer" />

    <!--app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"-->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/shadow"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        </FrameLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/shadow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_1sdp"
            android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"
            android:background="@color/shadow"/>


        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/navigationitem"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/navigationitem"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_item"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I want to create both navigation drawer and bottom navigation in the same activity. I created `XML` design now I have to write java code for both. Bottom navigation is working perfectly but navigation item `clicklistener` is not working. I created fragments for navigation drawer and also for bottom navigation. When I click the items in navigation drawer it's not redirecting to respective fragment. The given `clicklistener` for navigation drawer is not at all working.

Comment: check your code carefully. You have commented out the setUpNavigationView() method in your onCreate()

Comment: i tried already its not working that's y i commented it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solution:**

Try the following steps to get it working:

**Step1:** Implement `onNavigationItemSelected` as shown below:

```
.... extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
```

**Step2:** Use the method generated by the interface as:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.your_drawer_item_id:
            ....
            ....
        case R.id.your_drawer_item_id:
            ....
            ....
    }
}
```

**Step3:** In your class declare a Global variable:

```
public NavigationView navigationView;
```

**Step4:** In your `onCreate()` initialize the variable as:

```
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.your_nav_view);
```

**Finally:** Setup the navigationView:

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

That's it.

Hope it works.

DrawerLayout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_vendor_drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemBackground="@android:color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_color"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_vendor_drawer_layout"
        app:menu="@menu/vendor_drawer_menu" >

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_vendor_drawer_layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="logixtic.android.web.vd.driver.activities.DriverDrawerActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/Project_Standard"
            app:popupTheme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation">

    </FrameLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow_above"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/White"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_color"
        app:menu="@menu/vendor_bottom_navigation"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Try it.

Comment: see my updated code above i changed like what u suggested

Comment: @DeepaDinesh Put a break at every case and at the end return true not return false and try. It will work, it's a code from my project, I too have Nav drawer and bottom nav in the same activity.

Comment: yeah i changed like that also

Comment: I too have the same situation in my project but it works, When you press any item from Drawer nothing happens? does it closes? @DeepaDinesh

Comment: i tried to debug.debug is not at all coming inside the listener

Comment: yeah when i select the item in navigation drawer its getting closed

Comment: Okay, In my project, NavigationView is inside Drawer but BottomNavigation is in another layout file and I have used <include> to include it inside Drawer. Would you like to try this. I'll post my code?

Comment: thanks a lot i will try with the updated code and let u know whether its working or not

Comment: @DeepaDinesh You're Welcome. I know it works in mine so definitely it will work. Happy Coding.

Comment: i want to set the text or image inside the toolbar for each fragment.How to set text or image in center of the toolbar.

Comment: You cannot set them in the center of the toolbar, it's not allowed, You can use a ConstraintLayout which looks like a toolbar and set it. @DeepaDinesh

Comment: the toolbar which is in MainActivity is coming for all fragments

Comment: i want to change the text in all fragments

Comment: If i create new constraint layout the page is  like refreshing when i select the fragments

Comment: Oh I thought you have a toolbar inside every Fragment @DeepaDinesh

Comment: Can you post another question on this, and provide some code of the xml and java. @DeepaDinesh

Comment: no.if had like that the page is refreshing like web pages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181600/discussion-between-deepa-dinesh-and-umang-burman).

Answer (score 1):

You can use on the same activity using a method that recive a MenuItem parameter like this:

```
private void myClickItem(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.bottom_home:
            // DO SOMETHING
            break;

        case R.id.drawer_main:
            // DO SOMETHING
            break;
      }
}
```

Then, call like this:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView =  findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> { // using lamda
     myClickItem(item); //call here
     return true;
});

NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nv);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
    myClickItem(item); // call the same method here

    drawerLayout.closeDrawers(); // bonus: hide navigation after click
    return false;
});
```

You don't need to modify your xml res, it'll work fine.